# How to prevent row check being skipped when the previous row is checked and deleted?

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, for-loop

This is intended to loop through two columns and verify that the value in the L column is lower than a specific (single) value in a cell from another sheet. It also checks to see if there is an "#N/A" error in the cell on the same row in column M. If these are true then the entire row is deleted. The code below appears to work, however, I have to run the For loop multiple time to get fully delete all the rows. My hunch is that when a row is deleted it's not checking the one right below it and moving on. How can I avoid this? Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub removerows()

Dim wsOut As Worksheet
Dim wsPrev As Worksheet
Dim r As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long

Set wsOut = Worksheets("Output")
Set wsPrev = Worksheets("Previous")
Lastrow = wsOut.UsedRange(wsOut.UsedRange.Cells.Count).Row

For r = 2 To Lastrow
    If wsOut.Cells(r, "L").Value < wsPrev.Cells(2, "L").Value And _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(wsOut.Cells(r, "M").Value) Then
              wsOut.Cells(r, "L").EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            wsOut.Cells(r, "L").Interior.ColorIndex = 20
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: When you delete a row, you are "promoting" the next row to the r-th position (replacing the current row), so when you increment to the next r, it naturally skips the row you just bumped up. It also looks like you will have a problem at the bottom because Lastrow (the number of total rows) remains the same even though you have deleted rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a reverse loop.

Change `For r = 2 To Lastrow` to `For r =  Lastrow to 2 Step -1`.

Didn't test it as I am on mobile but this should resolve your issue.

Comment: That's the one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub removerows()

    Dim wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim wsPrev As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long
    Dim Lastrow As Long

    Set wsOut = Worksheets("Output")
    Set wsPrev = Worksheets("Previous")
    Lastrow = wsOut.UsedRange(wsOut.UsedRange.Cells.Count).Row

    For r = Lastrow To 2 step -1
        If wsOut.Cells(r, "L").Value < wsPrev.Cells(2, "L").Value And _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(wsOut.Cells(r, "M").Value) Then
                  wsOut.Cells(r, "L").EntireRow.Delete
            Else
                wsOut.Cells(r, "L").Interior.ColorIndex = 20
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

The idea is to make the loop backwards, if you are deleting.

Answer (score 0):

you could speed it up and avoid loops by use of `AutoFilter()`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub removerows()
    Dim prevValue As Double

    prevValue = Worksheets("Previous").Range("L2")
    With Worksheets("Output") '<--| reference your "output" sheet
        With .Range("M1", .Cells(.Rows.count, "L").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its columns "L:M" range from row 1 (header) down to column "L" last not empty row
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<" & prevValue '<--| 1st filter on column "L" with values lower than sheet "previous" sheet "L2" cell
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="#N/A" '<--| '<--| 2nd filter on column "M" with values "#N/A" values
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then .Resize(.Rows.count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete '<--| if any filtered cells then delete their row
            .AutoFilter '<--| remve filters
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & prevValue '<--| filter on column "L" with values greater or equal than sheet "previous" sheet "L2" cell
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then .Resize(.Rows.count - 1, 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.ColorIndex = 20 '<--| if any filtered celld then color them
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add r = r - 1 after the row is deleted.

```
Sub removerows()

Dim wsOut As Worksheet
Dim wsPrev As Worksheet
Dim r As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long

Set wsOut = Worksheets("Output")
Set wsPrev = Worksheets("Previous")
Lastrow = wsOut.UsedRange(wsOut.UsedRange.Cells.Count).Row

For r = 2 To Lastrow
    If wsOut.Cells(r, "L").Value < wsPrev.Cells(2, "L").Value And _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(wsOut.Cells(r, "M").Value) Then
              wsOut.Cells(r, "L").EntireRow.Delete
    *****     r = r -1 'Done! it will recheck the same cell after 
        Else
            wsOut.Cells(r, "L").Interior.ColorIndex = 20
    End If
Next

End Sub
```